# NSData is nil in sendSynchronousRequest

Tags: ios, rest, ios9

I want to send some information encoded as JSON. My code worked in iOS 8.X but now not iOS 9.X.

```
CadenaConParametros = @"webme.mydomain.com/json/name/age/";
NSString *str = CadenaConParametros;
    NSURL *WcfSeviceURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[str stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];] init];

[request setURL:WcfSeviceURL];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSData *respData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
```

but the variable "respData" is nil, and the console doesn't show anything.

I have configured my "info.plist":

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>http://webme.mydomain.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Because `sendSynchronousRequest` is deprecated in iOS 9.Try use other networking API like `NSURLSession`

Comment: Also, your exception domain key is wrong. It should be a domain, not a URL - so "webme.mydomain.com" without the HTTP and forward secrecy true or false makes no sense in the context of HTTP

Comment: Use `NSURLSession` which is available since iOS 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I think you should ensure your URL (NSURL WcfSeviceURL) is valid before being set to your request.

Secondly, as you know, `[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:]` is deprecated in iOS 9, so you should use `NSURLSession` instead.

```
NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithURL:WcfSeviceURL completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (error) {
    } else {
    }
}];

[task resume];
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I had this code below of the variable "respData" `NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                          JSONObjectWithData: respData
                          options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                          error:&error];
    NSString *isSuccessNumber = (NSString*)[json objectForKey:@"InsertEmployeeMethodResult"];` Now how can I change that for my new code with `NSURLSession`

Comment: You can handle it inside the completion handler block: completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error)